# Save Model class object in SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am new to android development. I am saving user profile information in shared preferences so that whenever I am required to show the user name, email or other data I call it from shared preferences instead of calling from the database again and again. I want to save and get a complete profile instead of getting a single string. Below are functions I use

```
public void save(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor
        = context.getSharedPreferences("data", context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

public String get(String key) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences
        = context.getSharedPreferences("data", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
}
```

The function I want is something like below

```
public void save(String key, MyModel object) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor
        = context.getSharedPreferences("data", context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(key, object);
    editor.commit();
}
```

But shared preferences take the only string to save and get. Is there any possible solution to save objects in it? Or any alternative to shared preferences. (excluding SQLite or another complex database)

Comment: Did you have the concept of JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one to save data

```
public void saveData(String key, MyModel object) {
    save(key, new Gson().toJson(object));
}
```

this one to get data

```
public MyModel getData(String key) {
    String data = get(key);
    return new Gson().fromJson(data, MyModel.class);
}
```

**How it works?**

This save method converts your model object into a JSON string and then the string is saved into shared preferences and the same in get function. It gets data in the form of JSON string and then it converts it to your object and returns a value.
For save and get use your own functions

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your object to Json then save it as a String in your shared preference like the code below:

```
public void save(String key, MyModel object) {
    String myObject = Gson().toJson(object);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor
        = context.getSharedPreferences("data", context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(key, myObject);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Then you can convert it back to object like this:

```
public MyModel get(String key) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences
        = context.getSharedPreferences("data", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String myObject = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
    return Gson().fromJson(myObject, MyModel.class);
}
```